# What are Fibonacci numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am aware of the sequence but not the pattern 0,1,1,2,3,5,8.....
If someone could explain the pattern they follow, that would be a lot of help.
I do understand they are in nature, but I am not exactly known of how.

Comment: $0+1=1;1+1=2;1+2=3;2+3=5;3+5=8\cdots$. Each term is the sum of the previous two terms, and that it starts with $0,1$ is a common convention.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: Fibonacci numbers represent the number of immortal rabbits at any given generation.

Comment: I'm not saying this is a bad question, but your confusion can be alleviated with a simple google search...

Answer (score 1):

The first Fibonacci is 1, then the following ones are calculated by adding the two previous fibonaccis.

- First: 1
- Second (0 + 1): 1
- Third (1 + 1): 2
- Fourth (1 + 2): 3
- Fifth (2 + 3): 5

And so on, the pattern is Fn = Fn-2 + Fn-1

Comment: You are aware that Fibonacci is the name of a person?

Comment: I am aware, I should have wrote first Fibonacci number. But the message was understood by the OP :)

Comment: Well, one could have gotten the idea that the Fibonaccis multiplied like rabbits.

Answer (score 1):

These numbers are replete with patterns:

$1^2=0\cdot 1 +1$

$1^2=1\cdot 2 -1$

$2^2=1\cdot 3 +1$

$3^2=2\cdot 5 -1$

$5^2=3\cdot 8 +1$

$8^2=5\cdot 13 -1$

etc

And $a_{n+1}a_{n-1}=a_n^2\pm 1$ with eg $a_0=1, a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}$ an integer can be used to define the sequence, as well as the simpler and better known linear recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

It is posible to give a recurrence relation with no difficult. For example if you define $a_1=a_2=1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+a_{n-1}$ for all $n\geq 3$. This describes the sequence. But an explicit form require more theory.

Answer (score 0):

For any 2 initial number $T_1$ and $T_2$, we can obtain a Fibonacci sequence by using the following recursive formula:

$$T_n=T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}$$

So, in your case, $T_1=0$ and $T_2=1$,

$$T_3=T_2+T_1=1+0=1$$

$$T_4=T_3+T_2=1+1=2$$

$$T_5=T_4+T_3=1+2=3$$

$$T_6=T_5+T_4=2+3=5$$

$$T_7=T_6+T_5=3+5=8$$

and so on.

Similarly, other Fibonacci sequences can be obtained using other initial $T_1\ \ and \ \ T_2$ values.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the Fibonacci series is represented by $T_{n-1}+T_{n-2} = T_n$, where $T(0) = 0, T(1) = 1$. However, I would like to add that the Fibonacci series also has a closed form, meaning it is not defined by the previous terms. The closed form is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}[p^n-q^n]$ where $p = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ and $q = \frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}$. I will not go into how this is derived, but the best proof I could find can be found [here](http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~ksmani/courses/fa04/at/qen/fib.pdf). One other interesting fact about the Fibonacci series is that as the Fibonacci numbers get bigger, the ratio between them (that is $T_{n+1}:T_{n}$) approaches $\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$. This number, also called phi, or the golden ratio, occurs in nature quite a bit. Some examples of this are shown [here](http://www.natures-word.com/sacred-geometry/phi-the-golden-proportion/phi-the-golden-proportion-in-nature).